# Azure DevOps pipeline triggering as many times as number of stages, despite adding stage filter

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I've created two sample pipelines & added stage filter within second pipeline to run only on successful completion of 'Invoke' stage of startup pipeline. However, the second pipeline gets triggered after each stage completion of the startup pipeline.

According to MS docs I expected the second pipeline to be automatically triggered only once. I've provided the sample code & screenshots below, please help me figure out what am I missing:

Startup pipeline:

```
name: 'startup_pipeline'

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: invoke
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo "Starting up onboarding"

- stage: validate
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo "Verifying the pipeline run results"
```

pipeline-2:

```
name: '2_storage'

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: startup_pipeline
    source: startup_pipeline
    trigger:
      stages:
      - invoke

stages:
- stage: qa
  condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'],'master')
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo "Ran after startup in feature branch"

- stage: dev
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'],'master')
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo "Deployed to Dev"

- stage: test
  dependsOn: dev
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'],'master')
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo "Deployed to Test"

- stage: prod
  dependsOn: test
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'],'master')
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo "Deployed to Prod"
```

Manually triggered startup pipeline:
[image]

Second pipeline gets automatically triggered upon each stage completion of startup pipeline, instead of just after 'Invoke' stage completion:
[image]

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're not disabling your CI triggers, you're telling it to trigger on a branch named `none`.

Comment: @DanielMann `trigger: none` can be used to disable CI trigger as per [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/trigger?view=azure-pipelines#trigger-none)

Comment: Yes, `trigger: none` does that. However, `trigger:` followed by a newline and the value `- none` is **not the same thing**; it's an instruction to trigger on a branch named `none`.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for pointing it out, I changed it to `trigger: none` but still see the same behavior that second pipeline gets triggered upon each stage completion.